# PdfTexify versus dvi2pdf: problem with eps figure

Tags: graphics, pdf, eps, winedt

I have problem to get eps pictures when I use PdfTexify in WinEdt 8.0 (MikTeX 2.9).
It works if I use dvi2pdf, but I prefer PdfTexify, because it allows me to include attachments in pdf file as well as to make hyperlinks on references.
Here is sample code

```
\documentclass[aps,pra,amsmath,amssymb,twocolumn,showpacs]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{epsf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{attachfile}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
   \epsfxsize=6.5cm\centering{\epsfbox{f/1.eps}}
\end{figure}
check attached here \attachfile{2013-05-17.nb}
\end{document}
```

Also, I would like to know which of those two ways to get PDF output is more preferred/professional? Or is there a more professional way? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, `epsf` is a package designed to include `.eps` files in plain `.tex` files.

Anyway, if you want to continue using it in your document and, at the same time, you want to solve your problems with attached files, you can use the package `attachfile2` with the option `dvipdfmx` instead of the package `attachfile`.

Simply substitute the line

```
\usepackage{attachfile}
```

with

```
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{attachfile2}
```

so to have

```
\documentclass[aps,pra,amsmath,amssymb,twocolumn,showpacs]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{epsf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{attachfile2}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
   \epsfxsize=6.5cm\centering{\epsfbox{f/1.eps}}
\end{figure}
check attached here \attachfile{2013-05-17.nb}
\end{document}
```

Now you will be able to have the `.pdf` with the correct references to attached files compiling with the sequence `latex` -> `dvi2pdf` in WinEdt.

---

In regards of WinEdt, I remind you that `PDFTeXify` is a command that runs `pdflatex`, `bibtex` and `makeindex` as many times as needed for a completely compiled `.pdf` file.

You can change its behavior to run `latex` and subsequently `dvipdfmx` instead of `pdflatex` to accomplish your needs.

To do that, run the "Execution Modes" interface from the "Options" menu. Then select the page "TeX Options" and change the "PDFTeXify Method" from "Default" to "dvi -> pdf", as shown in the image below.

[image]

Turn things back to have its usual behavior.

---

### Update

Anyway, I think you'd better use a more modern way to load `.eps` files in your document and use `pdflatex` to compile it.

I suggest to use the `epstopdf` package, which converts your `1.eps` file to `1-eps-converted-to.pdf` at runtime and uses it instead of the `.eps` one.

Remember to load the `epstopdf` package after `graphicx` or you might get errors.

Your MWE can be rewritten as

```
\documentclass[aps,pra,amsmath,amssymb,twocolumn,showpacs]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{attachfile}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=6.5cm]{f/1.eps}
\end{figure}
check attached here \attachfile{2013-05-17.nb}
\end{document}
```

and compiled with `PDFTeXify` with no changes in WinEdt.

Comment: thank you for answer, but your code gives following error when I TeXify:

! Package keyval Error: dvipdfmx undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
l.273 \ProcessKeyvalOptions{AtFi}
? 
Process has been terminated ...

Also what would you suggest for using eps files more professionally? Can you provide simple example?

Comment: @eRic I cannot reproduce the error with the MWE. You are talking about another file and I don't know what it contains...

Comment: @eRic see the update in the answer about a "more professional" way.

Comment: I tried your 1st MWE and that gave me error. 
And your updated MWE works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: When I use PDFTexify using same eps file it decrease the quality of image, while with dvi2pdf the quality is much better. Do you know how can I improve image quality in final pdf file? I saw here http://ctan.sharelatex.com/tex-archive/support/epstopdf/epstopdf.man1.pdf that I can use --res=DPI for the resolution, but I don't know what would be the syntax for that option in WinEdt.

Comment: @eRic I think The link you've found is for `epstopdf` wrapper, not for the `epstopdf` package...

Comment: @eRic Try adding a line `\DeclareGraphicsRule{.eps}{pdf}{.pdf}{\epstopdfcall{epstopdf --res=600 #1 \noexpand\OutputFile}}` in your document (taken from `epstopdf` package documentation).

Comment: I've tried but it gives this error ! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \Gin@base 
                     \Gin@ext 
l.13 ...stopdf --res=600 #1 \noexpand\OutputFile}}                                                
?